# How to switch desktop to metro UI by code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I wonder how to switch desktop to metro UI programmatically. I know pressing Windows key can do it but how to do same thing by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the desktop application

1. You can you window service host. Refer to link [Pro-grammatically open window start menu](http://crsouza.blogspot.in/2009/01/programmatically-opening-windows-start.html)
2. Use P/Invoke to send window key (From the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/46731/Open-Start-Menu))

   ```
   private static extern int keybd_event(Byte bVk, Byte bScan, long dwFlags, long dwExtraInfo);
   private const byte UP = 2;
   private const byte CTRL = 17;
   private const byte ESC = 27;

   Finally on the event where you want to open start menu use :
   // Press Ctrl-Esc key to open Start menu
   keybd_event(CTRL, 0, 0, 0);
   keybd_event(ESC, 0, 0, 0);

   // Need to Release those two keys
   keybd_event(CTRL, 0, UP, 0);
   keybd_event(ESC, 0, UP, 0);
   ```

For the modern UI app, I am not sure if it is possible to do so due to limited API support.